# What is Chardham Yatra in Hinduism?

Tags: worship, pilgrimage

Can someone tell what do Chardham Yatra means in Hindu religion. Many people every year undertake this yatra. It is said that the yatra holds religious importance in Hindus. So please explain about the yatra.

Comment: Read this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2475/647 look for the para where "chardham" is mentioned.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Char_Dham

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Char Dham?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22470/what-are-char-dham)

Comment: @YDS When I searched for chardham it didn't show this question in result. Seeing your comment I noticed I forgot to put space in between. :(

Comment: No worries @TheLittleNaru to ..it happenes sometimes... :)

Comment: I believe the context is different for different communities for uttrakhand pilgrimage it is Badrinath,kedarnath, gangotri and yamunotri

Comment: Another context i can tell you in terms of direction.. 1. Kasi 2. Rameshwara 3. Puri and Dwarak..@Archit but madhva community dissuades one from visting Kedarnath, as per MBTN of sriman maddhvacharya Kedarnath is meditating place of  lord shiva, one would face wrath of shiva who visits kedarnath for distrubing meditation of Shiva. he had already shown by cloud brust and related death in the area @Archit

Answer (score 1):

As per the article [the-coming-of-hastamalaka](https://www.sringeri.net/history/sri-adi-shankaracharya/biography/abridged-madhaviya-shankara-digvijayam#the-coming-of-hastamalaka) from [official site](https://www.sringeri.net/) of Sringeri mutt, Shankaracharya established 4 mutt(associated with 4 dhams Badrinath, Dwarka, Puri and Sringeri) in four directions in order to spread the spiritual wisdom and peace for all the seekers. Therefore as per this we can make out that people do this chardham yatra for addhyatmic(spiritual) progress and peace.

> ## The four Amnaya Mutts
>
> **Shankara consolidated his work by establishing in the four directions, four Mutts called Amnaya Mutts to sustain and foster the sacred tradition of Sanatana Dharma. Keeping in mind that the Mutts should serve as places of spiritual wisdom and peace for all seekers of the Truth**, Sri Shankara chose spots bountiful with natural splendor and serenity. **Sri Shankara chose Puri in the East and Dwaraka in the West, both being located on the shores of the sea. The Acharya also chose Badrinath in the North and Sringeri in the South for the natural aura that these places had, owing to the towering scenic mountains and at both places.**
> Sri Shankara assigned one Veda for each of the Mutts, signifying that each Mutt would play a significant role in taking efforts to sustain and propagate that particular Veda. Thus Rig, Yajur, Sama and Atharvana Veda were assigned to Puri, Sringeri, Dwaraka and Badrinath Mutts respectively. Sri Shankara also nominated his four chief disciples, one to each of these Mutts. He assigned Sureshwara to Sringeri, Padmapada to Dwaraka, Hastamalaka to Puri and Totaka to Badri. That all these Mutts function to this day shows the vigour of the movement started by Shankara for the propagation of Advaita Vedanta and Sanatana Dharma as a whole.